# working with an .aspx page with in asp.net mvc 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm new to asp.net mvc.

I just created the default asp.net mvc project in VS and I can see that when I make a call to a controller's action like this: "http://localhost:2528/Home/About" my Home controller has an action method "About" that is returning the about.aspx view.  however I am seeing not seeing the .aspx extension in the browser's url.  And when I try to browse to "http://localhost:2528/Home/About.aspx" i get a 404 error.

I have a requirement where I need to create a .aspx page that is passed an arguement via the url like this: "http://... /myAspxPageHere.aspx?argName=myArg"

I'm not sure how to do this with asp.net MVC.  Any help and/or code examples would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASP.Net MVC does not use the `.aspx` extension in client-facing URLs.

If you want to accept arguments from the querystring, you should add parameters to your action methods.

Comment: hmm, so something like this for my action method:  "public ActionResult About(int id)". This works but it won't let me keep the original About action that isn't parameterized.  I would still like to be able to make a call with no parameters (eg http://localhost:2528/Home/About.aspx).

Comment: @Ray: Make the parameter optional: `public ActionResult About(int? id = null)`  In C# 3.0, you'll need to apply `[DefaultValue(null)]` instead.